# number theory equation involving GCD

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Fix the natural number $b$. How can I solve ?
$$
x+\gcd(x,b) \equiv 0 \mod(b)
$$
Can anyone please give me a reference?
Best

Comment: Am I understanding correctly: For a fixed (but arbitrary) $b \in \mathbb{N}$, you are looking for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x + \gcd (x,b) \equiv 0 \pmod{b}$?

Comment: would $x=b-1$ when $b \ge 1$ count as a solution? Or do you want ALL solutions? (You would have to prove this as unique or investigate the other possible solutions)

Comment: The solutions are of the form $d(nb/d-1)$ for divisors $d\mid b$ and integers $n$.

Comment: Daniel: Yes!. Chubakueno: Yes!, but I am wondering for all the solutions !

Comment: Where does this problem come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=cd$ where $d=\gcd(x,b)$, and let $a:=b/d$. Then we have $\gcd(a,c)=1$, and
$$cd+d\equiv 0 \pmod{ad}$$
so that $c+1\equiv 0\pmod a$.

It means, that for *each* divisor $d$ of $b$, we can choose $c:\equiv -1\pmod{b/d}$, then $x:=cd$ will be a solution, as $c\equiv -1\pmod{a}$ already implies $\gcd(a,c)=1$ hence $\gcd(b,x)=d$.

Comment: But are these *all* the solutions?

Comment: Yes. I started out from an arbitrary solution.

Comment: wonderful! thanks Berci!